# A question about SharpDx Colored Cube

Tags: c#, directx11, sharpdx, vertex-buffer, index-buffer

Recently I start to study SharpDx, so I am a newbie for it.
  I try to create a cube which has difference color on each vertex such as the picture below.
[image]

However, what I created after my coding is something I'm not understand such as the picture below.

[image]
  I have checked my code many time but still couldn't find out what was wrong with it. I hope somebody can point it out for me. Many Thanks.

Hear is My Code

InitializeDirectX:

```
    int width = renderForm.ClientSize.Width;
    int height = renderForm.ClientSize.Height;
    Rational rational = new Rational(60, 1);
    ModeDescription backBufferDesc = new ModeDescription(width, height, rational, Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm);
    SwapChainDescription swapchainDesc = new SwapChainDescription
            {
                ModeDescription = backBufferDesc,
                SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
                Usage = Usage.RenderTargetOutput,
                BufferCount = 1,
                OutputHandle = renderForm.Handle,
                IsWindowed = true,
                SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard
            };
    SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device.CreateWithSwapChain(DriverType.Hardware, DeviceCreationFlags.None, swapchainDesc, out device, out swapChain);
    context = device.ImmediateContext;

    RasterizerStateDescription rasterDescription = RasterizerStateDescription.Default();
    rasterDescription.FillMode = FillMode.Solid;
    rasterDescription.CullMode = CullMode.None;
    rasterDescription.IsDepthClipEnabled = false;
    RasterizerState rasterizerState = new RasterizerState(device, rasterDescription);
    context.Rasterizer.State = rasterizerState;

    DepthStencilStateDescription depthStencilDesciption = DepthStencilStateDescription.Default();
    depthStencilDesciption.DepthComparison = Comparison.LessEqual;
    depthStencilDesciption.IsDepthEnabled = true;
    DepthStencilState depthStencilState = new DepthStencilState(device, depthStencilDesciption);
    context.OutputMerger.SetDepthStencilState(depthStencilState);

    Utilities.Dispose<RenderTargetView>(ref renderTargetView);
    Texture2D backBuffer = swapChain.GetBackBuffer<Texture2D>(0);
    renderTargetView = new RenderTargetView(device, backBuffer);
    backBuffer.Dispose();

    Texture2D zBuffer = new Texture2D(device, new Texture2DDescription
            {
                Format = Format.D16_UNorm,
                ArraySize = 1,
                MipLevels = 1,
                Width = renderForm.ClientSize.Width,
                Height = renderForm.ClientSize.Height,
                SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
                Usage = ResourceUsage.Default,
                BindFlags = BindFlags.DepthStencil,
                CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.None,
                OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.None
            });
    depthStencilView = new DepthStencilView(device, zBuffer);
    zBuffer.Dispose();

    context.Rasterizer.SetViewport(0, 0, renderForm.ClientSize.Width, renderForm.ClientSize.Height);
    context.OutputMerger.SetTargets(depthStencilView, renderTargetView);
```

My Hlsl:

```
    cbuffer CameraConstant:register(b0) {
        matrix World;
        matrix View;
        matrix Projection;
    };

    struct VS_IN
    {
        float4 position : POSITION;
        float4 color : COLOR;
    };

    struct PS_IN
    {
        float4 position : SV_POSITION;
        float4 color : COLOR;
    };

    PS_IN VS(VS_IN input)
    {
        PS_IN output = (PS_IN)0;
        output.position = mul(input.position, World);
        output.position = mul(output.position, View);
        output.position = mul(output.position, Projection);
        output.color = input.color;

        return output;
     }

     float4 PS(PS_IN input) : SV_Target
     {
        return input.color;
     }
```

LoadContent：

```
    filename = "Hlsls\\cube.txt";
    shaderByteCode = ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile(filename, "VS", "vs_5_0");
    vertexShader = new VertexShader(device, shaderByteCode);
    shaderSignature = ShaderSignature.GetInputSignature(shaderByteCode);
    inputLayout = new InputLayout(device, shaderSignature, new InputElement[]
            {
                new InputElement("POSITION",0,Format.R32G32B32_Float,0,0),
                new InputElement("COLOR",0,Format.R32G32B32_Float,12,0)
            });

    shaderByteCode = ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile(filename, "PS", "ps_5_0");
    pixelShader = new PixelShader(device, shaderByteCode);

    Eye = new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.5f);
    Target = new Vector3(0.0f, -0.1f, 0.0f);
    CameraUp = Vector3.UnitY;

    Angle = (float)Math.PI / 3.0f;
    Ratio = (float)(renderForm.ClientSize.Width) / (float)(renderForm.ClientSize.Height);
    NearestSight = 0.1f;
    FarrestSight = 100.0f;

    Projection = Matrix.Transpose(Matrix.PerspectiveFovLH(Angle, Ratio, NearestSight, FarrestSight));
    View = Matrix.Transpose(Matrix.LookAtLH(Eye, Target, CameraUp));
    World = Matrix.Transpose(Matrix.RotationY(0));
    CameraConstant camera = new CameraConstant();
    camera.World = World;
    camera.View = View;
    camera.Projection = Projection;
    constantBuffer = SharpDX.Direct3D11.Buffer.Create(device, BindFlags.ConstantBuffer, ref camera);

    verts = new PositionColorVertex[]
            {
                new PositionColorVertex(new Vector3(-0.5f,-0.5f,-0.5f),new Vector3(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f)),
                new PositionColorVertex(new Vector3(-0.5f,-0.5f,0.5f),new Vector3(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f)),
                new PositionColorVertex(new Vector3(-0.5f,0.5f,-0.5f),new Vector3(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f)),
                new PositionColorVertex(new Vector3(-0.5f,0.5f,0.5f),new Vector3(0.0f,1.0f,1.0f)),
                new PositionColorVertex(new Vector3(0.5f,-0.5f,-0.5f),new Vector3(1.0f,0.0f,1.0f)),
                new PositionColorVertex(new Vector3(0.5f,-0.5f,0.5f),new Vector3(1.0f,0.0f,1.0f)),
                new PositionColorVertex(new Vector3(0.5f,0.5f,-0.5f),new Vector3(1.0f,1.0f,0.0f)),
                new PositionColorVertex(new Vector3(0.5f,0.5f,0.5f),new Vector3(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f))
            };
    vertexBuffer = SharpDX.Direct3D11.Buffer.Create(device, BindFlags.VertexBuffer, verts);

    indeces = new int[]
            {
                0,2,1,1,2,3,
                4,5,6,5,7,6,
                0,1,5,0,5,4,
                2,6,7,2,7,3,
                0,4,6,0,6,2,
                1,3,7,1,7,5
            };
    indexBuffer = SharpDX.Direct3D11.Buffer.Create(device, BindFlags.IndexBuffer, indeces);
```

RenderEffect:

```
    context.ClearRenderTargetView(renderTargetView, backgroundColor);
    context.ClearDepthStencilView(depthStencilView, DepthStencilClearFlags.Depth, 1.0f, 0);
    context.VertexShader.Set(vertexShader);
    context.VertexShader.SetConstantBuffer(0, constantBuffer);
    context.PixelShader.Set(pixelShader);
    context.InputAssembler.SetVertexBuffers(0, new VertexBufferBinding(vertexBuffer, Utilities.SizeOf<PositionColorVertex>(), 0));
    context.InputAssembler.SetIndexBuffer(indexBuffer, Format.R16_UInt, 0);
    context.InputAssembler.PrimitiveTopology = SharpDX.Direct3D.PrimitiveTopology.TriangleList;
    context.InputAssembler.InputLayout = inputLayout;
    context.DrawIndexed(indeces.Length, 0, 0);
    swapChain.Present(1, PresentFlags.None);
```

Many Thanks to the one who can point out my problems in these codes.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found what the problem is.
  My indeces is an array which type is int, so during my render period, I should set my index buffer format 32byte such as Format.R32_UInt, rather than Format.R16_UInt. After I update the format that related to the indexbuffer and , bingo, the problem is solved.